# Error after installing comtypes-1.1.7 via pip from zip file

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6, comtypes

I downloaded [comtypes](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/releases) in zip file and used `pip install comtypes-1.1.7.zip` to install it. Successfully installed, but when I try to import the module, it shows error message:

```
>>> import comtypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python367\lib\comtypes\__init__.py", line 381
except COMError, err:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is valid only for Python 2. The code obviously was not fully updated for Python 3. Report the bug at their tracker.

Answer (score 0):

phd's answer is right. I successfully fixed this error using anaconda distrib.
Just replace the content of the directory Lib\site-packages\comtypes with the anaconda directory's content.